# Is there a way to generate a badge for the Dependabot into GitHub?

Tags: github, badge, dependabot

I've migrated a private GitHub repository to use the [new Dependabot](https://github.blog/2020-06-01-keep-all-your-packages-up-to-date-with-dependabot/#moving-forward-from-dependabot-com-and-dependabot-preview) (into GitHub) and now the Dependabot badge shows as it is inactive, on my `README.md`, but it's working fine.

[image: Dependabot Status]

I'm looking for a way to fix the badge to reflect the real status.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/1912) tracking this (currently in the Github team's backlog).